# VS code's launch.json arguments inserting quotes, causing Django extensions to fail

Tags: django, visual-studio-code

I am having trouble getting the "Run" option in VS Code working with Django Extensions. Django Extensions is an add-on which allows you to quickly spin up a TLS (SSL) endpoint.

The way I typically start django is `./manage.py runserver_plus --cert /tmp/ 8000`. I am attempting to replicate the same command by using the following fields in `launch.json`:

```
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver_plus",
                "--cert /tmp/",
                "8000"
            ],
```

However, the execution in the terminal is as follows:

```
$ /home/farhan/src/axial/manage.py runserver_plus "--cert-file /tmp/abc123" 8000
usage: manage.py runserver_plus [-h] [--ipv6] [--noreload] [--browser] [--nothreading] [--threaded] [--output OUTPUT_FILE] [--print-sql] [--truncate-sql TRUNCATE_SQL] [--print-sql-location]
                                [--cert CERT_PATH | --cert-file CERT_PATH] [--key-file KEY_FILE_PATH] [--extra-file EXTRA_FILES] [--reloader-interval RELOADER_INTERVAL] [--reloader-type RELOADER_TYPE]
                                [--pdb] [--ipdb] [--pm] [--startup-messages STARTUP_MESSAGES] [--keep-meta-shutdown] [--nopin] [--nostatic] [--insecure] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS]
                                [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color] [--force-color]
                                [addrport]
manage.py runserver_plus: error: unrecognized arguments: 8000
```

It seems that inserting is causing a problem. I have tried rearranging the second two arguments, but the result is no different.

Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: Does splitting `"--cert /tmp/"` into two separate arguments work? `"--cert", "/tmp/",`

Comment: @IainShelvington, please make this an answer. Been searching the web for this fix and it was so simple. Seems like there can be no spaces in the args string. Each argument and value needs to be in there own element of the "args" array as Iain mentioned.